# many to many relationship sql

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

[image]

What can i add to these three tables to allow a "family" to have many students and a family to have many parents?

i am struggling to get my head around what i could add which would allow me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: 1. You need a new table for family-student mapping. 2. More than 2 parents in a family?

Comment: Just do an inner join on your foreign keys with Family as the primary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a foreign key in student and parent that maps back to family_id, 
 Remove parent_id and student_id in the Family table.
If you need to find all member of family 22

```
select * from family f 
join parent p on f.family_id=p.family_id
join student s on s.family_id=f.family_id
where f.family_id=22
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it easier to understand! got it sorted now